# Expected location of a non-homogeneous random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $p_1,\dots,p_T$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $B_1,\dots,B_T$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\Pr[B_t=1]=p_t$ and $\Pr[B_t=-1]=1-p_t$. Is there any good lower bound of $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^T B_t\right|\right]$$

Comment: You can use Jensen's inequality on the convex function $|x|$ to say $$E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^TB_t\right|\right]\geq \left|\sum_{t=1}^TE[B_t]\right|= \left|\sum_{t=1}^T(2p_t-1)\right|$$

Comment: The above Jensen's inequality bound is asymptotically tight in the sense that: $$ \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{T}\left(E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^TB_t\right|\right]-\left|\sum_{t=1}^T(2p_t-1)\right|\right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how tight this bound has to be or what you intend to use it for, but an easy one would be
$$\mathbb E \left(\left|\sum_{t=1}^T B_t\right|\right)\ge=T\left(\prod_{t=1}^T p_t+\prod_{t=1}^Tq_t\right),$$
where $q_t=1-p_t$.

To see that this is true, note that $$\mathbb P(B_1+\ldots+B_T=T)=p_1\cdots p_T$$
(that is, every $B_t$ takes the value $1$), and
$$P(B_1+\ldots+B_T=-T)=q_1\cdots q_T$$
(all them are $-1$). Then,
$$P(|B_1+\ldots+B_T|=T)=p_1\cdots p_T+q_1\cdots q_T.$$

And so, one term of the expectacion is $T(p_1\cdots p_T+q_1\cdots q_T)$, and this is a lower bound, since all the other terms when calculating the expectation are also positive.

Comment: That looks like a correct bound, but unfortunately it goes to zero at $T\rightarrow\infty$ whenever there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $p_t, q_t \in [\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$  for all $t$.

Comment: Indeed, since it is smaller than $2T(1-\epsilon)^T$. Nice remark. It might however not be the case if there is no such $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment: From Jensen's inequality we get 
$$ E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^T B_t\right|\right] \geq \left|E\left[\sum_{t=1}^T B_t\right]\right| = \left|\sum_{t=1}^T(2p_t-1)\right|$$

---

For tightness we observe
$$\sum_{t=1}^T B_t = \sum_{t=1}^T(2p_t-1) + \sum_{t=1}^T (B_t-E[B_t])$$
So
$$\left|\sum_{t=1}^T B_t\right| \leq \left|\sum_{t=1}^T(2p_t-1)\right| + \left|\sum_{t=1}^T (B_t-E[B_t])\right|$$
So 
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{t=1}^T (2p_t-1)\right| &\leq E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^TB_t\right|\right] \\
&\leq  \left| \sum_{t=1}^T (2p_t-1)\right| + E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^T(B_t-E[B_t])\right|\right]
\end{align}
However
$$ E\left[\left|\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T(B_t-E[B_t])\right|\right] \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^T Var(B_t)}\rightarrow 0$$

---

Edit:  By similar reasoning we can get a stronger form of tightness of the above bound: If one of the two “drift” conditions hold:
$$\liminf_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}(2p_t-1)>0$$
or
$$\limsup_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}(2p_t-1)<0$$
then
$$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\left[E\left[\left|\sum_{t=1}^{T}B_t\right|\right]-\left|\sum_{t=1}^{T}(2p_t-1)\right|\right]=0$$
So the bound is very tight.  This objectively qualifies as a “good” lower bound.

Comment: In fact it can be shown that
$$ \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T(B_t-E[B_t])=0 \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your answer. But it seems to me that this inequality would not reduce to Khintchine inequality when all $p_t=1/2$.

Comment: This question focuses on the case of heterogeneous probabilities. Nonzero drift conditions such as I define in my edit above are natural in such cases, and they imply the expected distance grows linearly with time. You will not see square root behavior (such as in the Khintchine inequality) except for special cases such as the “zero drift” case you mention with $p_t=1/2$ for all $t$.